# Azure Veracode Upload and Scan Integration

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

What are the steps required to integrate a .NET (.NET 6.0) web application with Veracode Upload and Scan task in an Azure CI/CD pipeline?

According to Veracode's packaging requirements outlined in the documentation, I attempted to package the application, but it did not produce the desired results. Despite uploading the necessary pdb files, the Veracode scan results indicate that they are missing.

I have tried different publish commands, as listed below:

1. -c Debug -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile -p:UseAppHost=false -p:SatelliteResourceLanguages='en' --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
2. -c Debug --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)